# Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: jquery, ajax, blob

I am saving blob in database and I want to retrieve them and show them after ajax request become successful.

```
function specificreadURL(input) {
    console.log(input)
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    //reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input);
    reader.readAsDataURL(input);//line with error
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = reader.result;
        console.log(base64data);
    };

}
```

My code is above. The input is from ajax success. I tried to print in console to see what input is like. I am getting this in console.

[image]

1. How can I pass `blob` into `readAsDataURL()` like above `blob`
2. I want to convert blob to base64 so i can use it src in image.

***UPDATE***

```
function specificreadURL(input, type) {
    console.log(input)
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = reader.result;
        console.log(base64data);
    };
}

for (var j = 0; j < bblobfile.length; j++) {
    var blob = new Blob([bblobfile[j].blob], {
        type: bblobfile[j].type
    });
    specificreadURL(blob, bblobfile[j].type);
}
```

Tried above code it is giving me the correct type but the image file is not showing. I think the conversion has something do to with it.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A "little" late, but maybe it helps someone (or even you, if by any chance you didn't figure it out already)... assuming that `url` is your URL, `xhr` is your ajax / XMLHttp request, `reader` is your `FileReader` and `img` is your image, you should write something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    {
    if (((xhr.status === 200) || (xhr.status == 0)) && (xhr.response))
      {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {img.src = reader.result;}
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      }
    }
  }
xhr.send(null);
```

What this code does is basically:

- request the `url` using a `XMLHttpRequest` "GET"
- set the response type of that request to `blob` (not `json`, like you
  mentioned in the comments)
- on request completion (and if the `response` exists, so that you
  don't get errors like you got in the screenshot you posted!) set up
  the `reader` to read the response as a base64 dataURL and assign that
  base64 URL to the `src` attribute of your `img`.

If, as your code seems to do, you get the blobs from an DOM `input` element of type `file`, then, if that element is something like:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput">
```

the code becomes:

```
function readimg()
  {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {img.src = reader.result;}
  if (event.target.files[0]) {reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);}
  }

document.getElementById('fileinput').onChange = readimg;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The "input" is a binary string , not a blob.

If you want get a blob from ajax request just do :

```
xhr.responseType = "blob";
```

But if you want to be compatible with old browsers ( not support XHR2 ) , you need convert it to Uint8Array first .

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(input.length);
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    arr[i] = input.charCodeAt(i);
}
var blob = new Blob([arr.buffer]);
```

Comment: in my ajax request i am returning json do want to see the ajax request? i though its irrelevant so i didnt include in the question. there will be other data not only the blob

Comment: Oh sorry , you can try the second paragraph of the code , convert the binary string "input" to "blob" , then ```reader.readAsDataURL(blob);```.

Comment: Sir im am sorry if you got confused. The input in my code is a blob i want to convert it to base64 (to something like `"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeHp69MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9DYXR…AKdHJhaWxlcgo8PC9TaXplIDE4Ci9Sb290IDEgMCBSPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjg4MzEzCiUlRU9G".`) i want to use it as src